# How can I make Time Machine work with my Netgear WNDR3700 router?

Tags: network, time-machine, nas, afp, smb

The story is this:

I just upgraded to Mac OS Lion and as it turns out it won't work with my Samba share in the way Snow Leopard used to, for TimeMachine backups. After a bit of Googling I found that this is because TimeMachine now requires NetTalk 2.2 and AFP. So my question is this: How do I get an AFP share to work on my router? I currently use DD-WRT but I've had no luck installing custom software to it, recall it having something to do with there not being a package manager for the architecture used in the router I have.

I don't mind reflashing the router to either original firmware, if anyone can confirm that works, or some other firmware such as Tomato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discussion continues here: https://discussions.apple.com/message/15811189. I got the same answer there and asked some follow-up questions.

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://netatalk-ddwrt.blogspot.com/

Try the builds mentioned and install them on your router with the following commands:

ipkg install libdb_4.7.25-3_mipsel.ipk
ipkg install netatalk_2.2.0-2_mipsel.ipk

make sure that you use

ipkg install libdb_4.7.25-3_mipsel.ipk -force-downgrade

in case your libdb version is newer than 4.7.24.

Best regards,
 nGoot

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.